# xdebug 2 with PhpStorm setup error

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have been dealing with an unexpected error when trying to setup xdebug 2 with PhpStorm (2016.2.2). It says:

> Connection with 'xdebug 2.5.0rc1' was not established. Validate installation.

I decided to ask for help because I cannot solve this error for 3 days already and I have tried everything I could.

These are the setup steps that I did:

- pasted my phpinfo here (https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) and downloaded the recommended php_xdebug.dll (`php_xdebug-2.5.0rc1-5.5-vc11-nts-x86_64`).
- copied php.ini file into `bin\php\php5.6.0` and added these lines of code:
- `[Xdebug]`
  `zend_extension = C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0rc1-5.6-vc11.dll`
  `xdebug.default_enable=1`
  `xdebug.remote_enable=1`
  `xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM`
  `xdebug.remote_port = 80`
  `xdebug.profiler_enable=1`
- Installed "JetBrains IDE Support" and "Xdebug helper" extensions for Chrome browser.

Sometimes I manage to debug (I guess) without an error but I get an error on browser which says "No direct script access allowed".

I am on Windows 10 x64 running MAMP 3.2.2 with php 5.6.0. Don't know what more details I can provide right now but it looks enough.

Comment: I had to tell xdebug if it is enabled from remote and for which ip. I don't know if you need this if you debug on the same host as the server is. I've switched this in my .htaccess: `php_value xdebug.remote_host <remote-ip>, 
php_value xdebug.remote_enable 1`

Comment: remote_port = 80 ? not likely. Xdebug wants to communicate to Phpstorm, which can be configured to listen on a specific port (default 9000) if i recall. Look in "settings->languages & frameworks->PHP->Debug , you will see the Xdebug settings pane. Use the same port in your remote_port as the one you find there. If you change the php settings dont forget to restart your web server (and possibly php-fpm).

Comment: Official manuals (in case if you have not seen them yet): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: 2) You do not need "JetBrains IDE Support" for PHP debug -- it's for JavaScript/LiveEdit and similar stuff 3) *"xdebug.remote_port = 80"* -- that should be xdebug port (`9000` by default) and not your web server port. Please read xdebug docs. 4) Better use xdebug **2.4.1** instead -- some people have issues with 2.5 RC on Windows (e.g. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205417890-Adding-Debugger-Support-to-PhpStorm-Project)

Comment: 5) *"...but I get an error on browser which says "No direct script access allowed"* == sounds more like JavaScript debug to me and definitely not like PHP debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I had was on the other laptop that I use. Both of them use the same settings (win10, MAMP 3.2.2). On my second laptop (the one I am currently typing from) this is php.ini settings:

> PHP version: 5.6.0 PHP CLI: C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.0\php.exe PHP CGI:
>   C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.0\php-cgi.exe  Loaded Configuration File:
>   C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.0\php.ini Debugger extension: xdebug 2.4.1

It uses xdebug 2.4.1 and I dont get the error on this laptop. I will try to get the same xdebug version to my first laptop and see if it works.

And this is the only command I added to php.ini on the second laptop (xdebug functioning) "zend_extension = C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11.dll" . Does it even make sense that without extra Xdebug settings it could even run?

Comment: xdebug 2.5 RC is not usable right now on Windows: 1) https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1361 2) https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1366 . You need to **use xdebug 2.4.1** for now.

Comment: Exactly. Today I tested 2.4.1 and it worked fine. I will mark this post as solved.